# add style attribute to every two child element of a class, every class should behave independently including their last child (which has if statement)

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

**EDIT** please check answers, using javascript for this purpose is not good. I will leave this question as it is since it may correct someone else too.

my goal is every ".ulInCollapse li" should be calculated independently. I do achieve my goal if I give different class (or id) names like .ulInCollapse1 .ulInCollapse2 and so on but I know this is not the proper way. I also changed my js code to iterate through;

```
const ulInCollapse = document.querySelectorAll(".ulInCollapse");
console.log(ulInCollapse)
ulInCollapse.forEach(function (ulInCollapse) {
  var ulInCollapseLiCount = ulInCollapse.length;
  var ulInCollapseLiCountChild = document.querySelector(".ulInCollapse li:last-child");
  if (ulInCollapseLiCount % 2 != 0) {
    ulInCollapseLiCountChild.style.paddingTop = "15px";
  } else {
    ulInCollapseLiCountChild.style.paddingTop = "0px";
  }});
```

I couldn't figure out what should I do, I hope I am able to explain my problem clearly.

```js
// I am chosing every ".ulInCollapse li" and adding if statement to add padding for last child accordingly
const ulInCollapse = document.querySelectorAll(".ulInCollapse li");
var ulInCollapseLiCount = ulInCollapse.length;
var ulInCollapseLiCountChild = document.querySelector(".ulInCollapse li:last-child");
console.log(ulInCollapseLiCount);
if (ulInCollapseLiCount % 2 != 0) {
  ulInCollapseLiCountChild.style.paddingTop = "15px";
} else {
  ulInCollapseLiCountChild.style.paddingTop = "0px";

}
```

```css
/* here I am trying to add padding to every 2 li starting from the first */
.ulInCollapse li:nth-child(2n+1):not(:last-child) {
    padding: 15px 0px;
}

/* I am using js to add padding-top in this selector */
.ulInCollapse li:last-child {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <button class="collapsible">Basit Zamanlar (The
      Simple Tenses)</button>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
        <!-- question: add padding to every two element, how??? -->
        <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Geçmiş Zamanalar (The Past Tenses)</button>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
        <!-- question: add padding to every two element, how??? -->
        <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Gelecek Zamanlar (The Future Tenses)</button>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
        <!-- question: add padding to every two element, how??? -->
        <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure to understand the criteria. I see that your css rules for each parent select the 1st of each 3 siblings (2n+1). Did you expect something different. What's not behaving correctly? Maybe you meant to select the even numbers? or the odd?

Comment: @DiegoD neither odd nor even. actually I fixed my problem removing js and making it with css. I forgot to update this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant how to correctly set the padding of the last list item in each list found in the document via javascript.

This should do the trick but I'm not sure this was the best strategy to achieve that result. I mean a different approach using styles differently would be more elegant then settings padding that way.

I only addressed the javascript side of your code and on your css rule I added a red left border to see when the selector actually matched and an outline for every list item so that it was evident the correct padding applied.

```js
const ulInCollapse = document.querySelectorAll(".ulInCollapse");

//for each .ulInCollapse
ulInCollapse.forEach( ul => {
  //the number of li elements contained in the current ul
  const liCount = ul.querySelectorAll(':scope > li')?.length;
  //15px if liCount is odd, otherwise 0
  const padding = (liCount % 2 !== 0) ? '15px' : '0';
  //sets the the padding-top of the last li in this ul
  ul.querySelector(':scope > li:last-child').style.paddingTop = padding;
})
```

```css
/* here I am trying to add padding to every 2 li starting from the first */
.ulInCollapse li:nth-child(2n+1):not(:last-child) {
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-left: solid red;
}

/* I am using js to add padding-top in this selector */
.ulInCollapse li:last-child {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

li {
  outline: solid;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Basit Zamanlar (The
      Simple Tenses)</button>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
        <!-- question: add padding to every two element, how??? -->
        <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Geçmiş Zamanalar (The Past Tenses)</button>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
        <!-- question: add padding to every two element, how??? -->
        <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Gelecek Zamanlar (The Future Tenses)</button>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
        <!-- question: add padding to every two element, how??? -->
        <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And this is  much better solution to style elements inside a flex container. In the container I used `gap` to choose the distance between the elements and I specified `margin: 10em 0` to make spacing between its macro siblings. Using padding for spacing items is not a good idea because the padding is intended for spacing contents ***inside*** not outside.

This alone on the container will be enough to correctly set the layout for its items:

```
.ulInCollapse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 14px;    
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```css
.ulInCollapse {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 14px;    
  margin: 10px 0;
}

ul.ulInCollapse li {
  /*
    !!!!
    again this border is to highlight the elegance of this solution
    if you will set the borders to your solution that used paddings you'll see incongruent sizing
  */
  border: solid 1px;
}

ul.ulInCollapse li a {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
  font-size: large;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Basit Zamanlar (The Simple Tenses)</button>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
    <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="collapsible">Geçmiş Zamanalar (The Past Tenses)</button>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
    <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="collapsible">Gelecek Zamanlar (The Future Tenses)</button>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="ulInCollapse" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0%;">
    <li><a href="#">Simple Present Tense</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Simple Perfect Tense</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake and your time for answering, I upvoted this but I am not going to select it as answer in case my intention may lead someone to wrong way. I also posted my final code, I think it is more accurate in terms of better strategy now. yet I will not select it as answer too.

Comment: you still used padding to give spacing to your layout but that's semantically wrong actually. It will work but you are giving responsability for the layout to the child instead of the container. I added another snippet that uses a flex container

Comment: thank you for making it better, this is valuable lesson for me. I deleted my answer, and now your answer should be highlighted.